# SharePoint Online List view is not showing Item with Group By" filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-list-filter

In my SharePoint Online List, One of the views is having a problem as given below:

1. Adding One Filter to get specific data --> Item shows as expected.
2. Try to add a "Group By" filter, --> No Item Shows

The number of total List items is more than 25k. The Expected List View Item after filtration is 5k+.
Please suggest, what to do.

Comment: Did you try column indexing? Add your filter columns in indexing. re-index the list and wait for couple of hours(to complete reindexing-crawling).

Comment: Yes. Indexing and re-indexing have been done. When I was using the first filter, it was working fine. But it is giving an error only after using the 2nd filter "Group By".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a few reasons why your "Group By" filter isn't displaying items in your SharePoint Online list view. Here are some things you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check if the column you want to group by has any empty or missing
   values. If it does, try filtering out those items to see if the
   group by filter starts working.
2. Make sure the "Group By" column is part of the list view fields. If
   it's not, add it to the list view fields and then try applying the
   "Group By" filter again.
3. See if the "Group By" column is a calculated one. If it is,
   SharePoint Online may not be able to group by it. In this case,
   create a new column with the same formula as the calculated column
   and use it for the "Group By" filter.
4. If none of the above solutions work, it might be due to having too
   many items in the view. SharePoint Online has a limit on the number
   of items you can group in a single view. In this situation, create a
   new view with a filter that reduces the number of items in the view,
   and then apply the "Group By" filter.

I hope these suggestions help you resolve the issue with your SharePoint Online list view.

Comment: Thanks, Adnan. Your 1st point was my situation. It's a small thing which was giving me so much problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is likely due to the list view threshold limit of 5,000 items for a view in SharePoint Online. To solve this issue, you can index columns in that list or Edit the list view to reduce the number of items in the view for the affected to 5,000 items or less.

See this article for more information about managing large list in SharePoint:

- **[Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)**

Comment: In SharePoint Modern, I found that the 5000 items issue is not giving any problems. As for this particular list, I am getting items after 1st filter addition. But after adding the 2nd Filter with Group By, is gives an error that looks odd.